# Maven running tests annotated with junit @Ignore when building Java project

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, testing, junit

I've annotated a bad test with @Ignore, both on the method-level and on the class level. When running the test through the command line (I've tried "mvn clean install", "mvn test", "mvn clean install -DskipTests; mvn test"), however, the @Ignore annotation is ignored, the test is run, and- as it is a bad test- it fails.

Here is the test:

```
public class UserTest extends PersistentTestBase {
    @Test
    @Ignore
    public void testPersistence() {
    ...
    }
}
```

And here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

...
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

...

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
   ...

    <!-- Testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmock-legacy</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
...

<!-- For dep management, see Mykong.com's "How to create a jar file with Maven" -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Necessary to force language level of Java 8 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <junitArtifactName>junit:junit-dep</junitArtifactName>
                <useFile>false</useFile>
                <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <forkCount>1</forkCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Packages into a jar, looking for deps in target/dependency-jars -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/log4j.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>...Application</mainClass>
                        <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Moves all compiled deps to target/dependency-jars -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>...Application</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Worth noting that the test is skipping when the class is run in Intellij IDEA 14, and that there are some other issues with tests failing on mvn test that are passing in Intellij (but are out of the scope of this question). Thank you for the help!

Comment: Make sure you're using the `junit47` test runner.

Comment: I think you can simply remove: <junitArtifactName>junit:junit-dep</junitArtifactName> from the surefire config

Comment: @wemu Awesome, that worked, thank you! Why was that element breaking the test?

Comment: to be honest: I have no idea. the junit-dep artifact is quite old. I assumed it might not interpret the @Ignore annotaion (the junit packages changed in the past). So just a wild guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wemu posted the solution:

> I think you can simply remove:
>   junit:junit-dep from the
>   surefire config – wemu Nov 20 at 7:10

Removed the  element and all tests passed!

Answer (score 8):

For those who are working with `Junit` 5.

`@Ignore` did not work for`maven` `surefire` neither `Intellij` tests even if I had already included `junit-vintage-engine`

I used `@Disabled` and it worked for `maven` at least!

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem with the JUNIT library. After so many tries, it worked with the `Pom.xml` below:

```
<repositories>
<repository>
<id>junit</id>
<url>http://junit.org</url>
</repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
<dependency><groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.11</version></dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to simply update the JUnit version to 4.13:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.13</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```